# D3.js - Assigning X and Y axis domain as max and min of data

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

Working with JSON data, I am able to set a domain X and Y to the minimum and maximum value of their respective data attributes, using

```
.y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.peopleVisited + 100; })]))
```

Here is an exemplary jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5H3Ay/15/

Can someone please suggest how to achieve this with csv data, using d3.csv()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should not be any difference in setting the domain, as long as you format your (CSV-) data properly.

The [D3 Wiki page for CSV](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) says that, using *d3.csv.parse(string[, accessor])*:

> [For] the following CSV file:

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

> The resulting JavaScript array is:

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

... which is a valid JSON array.
If you add *peopleVisited* as a header field in your CSV-file, your code should work already.

Just set up your data variable with *csv.parse()*.

**Edit**
You can load your CSV, for example, by calling d3.csv() with an accessor function like this:

```
var data = d3.map();
d3.csv("../path/to/your/file.csv", /* accessor */ function(d) {
    data.set(d.id, d.peopleVisited);
});
```

... which uses the column *id* as the key.

Comment: I am sorry I did not get it when you say set up your data variable with csv.parse .. Can you site a brief example.

Comment: @Andy897 example added

Comment: Sorry but I am still not able to get it completely. You are suggesting to create a map in the above example ? And then use ?

Comment: Yes, that was basically the idea. You're going to need to convert your CSV to some kind of JS-compatible data structure in order to be able to work with d3. A map seemed like a sensible option, since you can use your pre-existing IDs (if any) and wrap the other properties in a plain object.     My point is that the accessor function might be the key to your problem. Otherwise you may clarify things, by adding some more context to your code snippet.